# Create list of one sub-column based on another column

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set that looks like:

```
Files          Batch
filepath1.txt   One
filepath2.txt   One
filepath3.txt   One
filepath4.txt   One
filepath5.txt   two
filepath6.txt   two
filepath7.txt   two
filepath8.txt   two
```

I want to loop over the full data set (that has a dozen "Batch" categories) by creating groups of "Files" that is based on what "Batch" they're in, in a new variable called "batch"

i.e.

```
batch[1] 
filepath1.txt
filepath2.txt
filepath3.txt
filepath4.txt

batch[2]
filepath5.txt
filepath6.txt
filepath7.txt
filepath8.txt
```

How do I do this for all my Batch groups in the full data-set?

Comment: `batch <- with(mydata,split(Files,Batch))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` function seems to be what you're looking for.

```
> dat <- data.frame(File = paste0("file", 1:10, ".txt"), Batch = rep(c("one", "two"), each = 5))
> dat
         File Batch
1   file1.txt   one
2   file2.txt   one
3   file3.txt   one
4   file4.txt   one
5   file5.txt   one
6   file6.txt   two
7   file7.txt   two
8   file8.txt   two
9   file9.txt   two
10 file10.txt   two
> split(dat, dat$Batch)
$one
       File Batch
1 file1.txt   one
2 file2.txt   one
3 file3.txt   one
4 file4.txt   one
5 file5.txt   one

$two
         File Batch
6   file6.txt   two
7   file7.txt   two
8   file8.txt   two
9   file9.txt   two
10 file10.txt   two
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I've not used split like that before. Thank you!

Comment: If you only want the files like you have in your example output then Ben's comment gets you what you want.  But split is basically what you want to use for this kind of situation.